# Enqueued jQuery not working

Tags: jquery

I am trying to change a label on the add new page for a custom post type, but I am having trouble getting any jQuery to operate.

In functions.php, I am enqueueing my script file, after first verifying the page, using the following

```
wp_enqueue_script('vrscripts', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/assets/js/vrscripts.js', array('jquery'), true);
```

The contents of vrscripts.js is

```
(function ($) {
// Your code inside here;
    var cur = $('div.edit-post-post-schedule span').text();
    alert(cur);        

})(jQuery);
```

The alert box displays, but shows only "localhost:5547 says " without showing the contents of the span.

I have also tried

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
// Your code inside here;
    var cur = $('div.edit-post-post-schedule span').text();
    alert(cur);        

});
```

but that yields the same result.

The relevant html section is

```
<div class="components-panel__row edit-post-post-schedule">
    <span>Publish</span>
    <div class="components-dropdown" tabindex="-1">
        <button type="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Change date: Immediately" class="components-button edit-post-post-schedule__toggle is-tertiary">Immediately</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

I know I must be missing something simple, but I am at a loss as to what it is. Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: could this not be handled when registering the post type in PHP?

Comment: Not so far as I know. I am using PODS and there was a label that I thought would work but did not.

Answer (score 0):

Someone answered, but the answer has since disappeared, which is a shame because it lead me to the solution. What ended up working was

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('div.edit-post-post-schedule span').text('Birth Date');
        $('div.edit-post-post-schedule span').css('font-weight','bold');
    }, 250);

});
```

I'm still a bit fuzzy on **why** it worked, but I will take the win!